# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failure parsing Toggle config resources when updating Scala version from 2.11 to 2.12

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle, scala-2.12

I have maven project with Scala and java. We are using twitter finagle library version 18.9.0.

The current version of scala is 2.11.11 and I want to update the version to 2.12.6.

When I compile the program now I get the below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failure parsing Toggle config resources for 
com.twitter.finagle.core, from 
jar:file:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.m2/repository/com/twitter/finagle- 
core_2.12/18.9.0/finagle-core_2.12- 
18.9.0.jar!/com/twitter/toggles/configs/com.twitter.finagle.core.json
```

Any idea why I get this error in scala 2.12 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I forced the build tool(maven) to use paranamer 2.8, the issue is solved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the solution in more details ? What parameters did you change ?